# Why is gparted not resizing a partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to partition a HDD that has Lubuntu on it that I was using for another computer so that I can install Ubuntu on the new partition. But its telling me that it failed by showing this:

```
Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to resize /dev/sda1
```

Anyway I can fix this?

I am shrinking it to get free space.

Comment: Setting up dual-boot (shrinking LUbuntu partition to get free space) or replacing old system (fresh partitioning for new Ubuntu only)?

Comment: run (from a live cd) 'e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 1):

Typically this means that there was an error reading from the disk.  In other words, you have a bad sector.  You should check `dmesg` or /var/log/kern.log to see if there are more detailed error messages bout the drive, as well as the SMART health in the disk utility, and if the drive has many reallocated or pending bad sectors, you need to back up what you can and replace the drive at once.  If it is only one or two, then you may be able to repair it.  Have a look around for questions relating to bad sectors for more information on that.